# Bind List of object array to ListView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listview, eval, bind

I am breaking my head to fix an issue.  I have a method that returns a `List<Object[]>`.

Each `object[]` in the List contains the following:

```
object[0]=Id;
object[1]=Name;
```

Now, I am looking for a way to bind this List to a ListView in a custom `ItemTemplate` which would look as follows:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"
    Text="Here want to do an Eval/Bind for object[0]"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"
    Text="Here want to do an Eval/Bind for object[1]"></asp:Label>
```

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your datasource is not capable for standard databinding. Convert it to a name value pair, which will have a name and a value for each item that will be binded. For example [Dictionary<string, string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) collection is compatible for this. And then just turn your ListView to this :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"
    Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>'></asp:Label>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"
    Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 6):

A list of object arrays is a poor choice to store items in. You should consider using a class that represents the item, or a Dictionary as @Canavar suggested. Then you would be able to use the Eval method in a cleaner fashion.

That said, it is possible to bind with your current setup, although the syntax makes my eyes bleed.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"
    Text='<%# ((Object[])Container.DataItem)[0] %>' />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"
    Text='<%# ((Object[])Container.DataItem)[1] %>' />
```