# Binding ListView to List<T> or List<InterfaceOfT> with object type

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Riding off the back of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407465/list-of-generics-t-using-interface), I finally have a complete List where Value has types like ushort, ulong, ect.

But when I bind it to a ListView and add items, I get "blank" rows. In other words the ListView acknowledges there are items but it won't visually display them. If I stop and debug it, I can clearly look into the values of the items but it appears the object type is breaking it.

```
public interface IStatistic
{
    object m_Min { get; set; }
    object m_Max { get; set; }
    object m_Avg { get; set; }
}

public class Statistic<T> : IStatistic
{
    public T m_Min;
    public T m_Max;
    public T m_Avg;

    object IStatistic.m_Avg
    {
        get{ return m_Avg;}
        set { m_Avg = (T)value; }
    }
    object IStatistic.m_Min
    {
        get{ return m_Min;}
        set { m_Min = (T)value; }
    }
    object IStatistic.m_Max
    {
        get{ return m_Max; }
        set { m_Max = (T)value; }
    }

    public Statistic(T min, T max, T avg)
    {
        m_Min = min;
        m_Max = max;
        m_Avg = avg;
    }
}

 public ObservableCollection<IStatistic> m_MyCollection { get; set; }
 m_MyCollection.add(new Statistic<ulong>(x, y, z));
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding m_MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Min" 
          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=m_Min, Converter={StaticResource typeConverter }}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Avg"  
          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=m_Avg}" />
           </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

I thought maybe the object type was throwing off the ListView, so I tried to make a type Converter but the type Converter never hits when debugging in this case for m_Min. I'm just trying to get anything to come up for the values.

```
  public class ObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.GetType().FullName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501913/bind-list-of-object-array-to-listview-in-asp-net) it may not be possible? But that is ASP.NET so I was hoping maybe I'm misunderstanding that in context to C# WPF .NET

Comment: Your ListView should be binding to m_MyCollection (its currently binding to t) Not sure if a typo

Comment: yes, typo indeed sorry! That was not the issue :P I wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings in WPF (and Silverlight) only work on *public properties*. Explicit interface implementations, while seeming public (they are public on the interface, after all) are actually implemented as *private* by the compiler, so you can't access them without casting the reference to the interface type beforehand.

Binding to fields (`public T m_Min;`) won't work as well, as the binding engine calls the accessor methods directly instead of "setting" or "getting" the property value.

The easiest way to fix your problem would be making your public fields automatically implemented properties. This will give the binding engine access to them while only requiring minimal changes to the code elsewhere (using them as ref/out arguments won't work anymore) and with almost no measurable performance overhead.

Comment: I thought maybe it was a permission issue, but I did exactly what you did with public T m_Min and dismissed it. It was in fact that fields not being automatically implemented. I added a {get; set;} to them, as Rohit displays, and it worked. I'd mark both as right if I could.

Answer (score 2):

The interface is implemented explicitly, so the regular binding syntax wont work in this case.

To make it work you must write it like this:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=(local:IStatistic.m_Min)}"
```

Now the values will show up in the `ListView` and there should be no binding errors anywhere.

You must remember to import the namespace of the `IStatistic` type.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot bind with fields** in WPF. Make your fields as **`automatic properties`** and your code will work:

```
    public T m_Min { get; set; }
    public T m_Max { get; set; }
    public T m_Avg { get; set; }
```